# Writing pandas df to xml file (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas df:

```
userid | fid | response
-----------------------
1125 | 58940 | xml1
3344 | 47839 | xml2
3455 | 12335 | xml3
```

I want to iterate this df row by row and insert each row into a file. Then convert the xml into json to store in mongodb. The xml is a large xml document.

The final result I want it like json like:

```
"userid" : "1125",
"fid" : "5890",
"response" : "xml1"
```

The xml1 is a big hierarchy.

So far, my code looks like this but I am going nowhere with it:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\xml.csv', sep = '|') 
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['userid', 'fid', 'response'])

file = 'file{}.xml'
    for row in df.iterrows():
        with open(file.xml, 'w') as f:
            f.write(row)
```

I want to use only one file rather than separate file for each row as there are more than 2 million records. Every row will be inserted into a document and after conversion it will clear the content before writing the next row.

Basically I need to write to a file just to convert it into json.

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Why don't you convert directly to json?

Comment: I can't because the xml document is dirty, as in, it contains things which are not xml. They are like headers and other stuff about the document. I need to clean it first.

Comment: @angelwally How can I directly convert it into json? Basically its a list of xmls. Can I convert a list of xmls directly to json?

Comment: I guess if you want to append each file into one file you should use `open(file.xml, 'a')`. `w` will truncate your first file first. I don't know the content of your xmls, but it might cause issue just to append multiple xmls directly.

Comment: That's what I want. The loop will continue after this to convert it into json. Once it is converted to json I don't need it anymore. So, it can truncate and with the next value in the loop, do the same thing.'

Comment: So what's your issue then? I am not sure to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160573/discussion-between-angelwally-and-karan-gupta).